# How to redraw or refresh in OnRender?

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, onrender

I want to draw something dynamically. Following code shows my OnRender. I'm setting DrawItem somewhere in my program where I need it. But when I'm calling `DrawItem =5;` what do I have to call, so that OnRender gets called?

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    switch (DrawItem)
    {
        case 1:
            //Draw Item 
            break;
        case 2:
            //Draw Item 
            break;
        case 3:
            //Draw Item 
            break;
        case 4:
            //Draw Item 
            break;
        case 5:
            //Draw Item 
            break;
    }
    base.OnRender(drawingContext)
}

public int DrawItem { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is not clear but from what I can understand you seem to be asking for a method to refresh the visuals after updating your drawing variables. You could use the following after updating your drawing variables:

```
this.InvalidateVisual();
```

and with the property:

```
private int drawItem;
pulic int DrawItem
{
 get {return drawItem;}
 set 
 {
    drawItem=value;
    this.InvalidateVisual();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

If the size of your control changes, you can use `InvalidateVisual()`, however keep in mind this causes a fairly expensive re-layout of your UI. If the size of your control is staying the same, you shouldn't call `InvalidateVisual()`.

A more efficient way to update your UI is to create a `DrawingGroup` "backing store" and add it to the `DrawingContext` during `OnRender()`. You can then update it whenever you like, using `DrawingGroup.Open()`, and WPF will update your UI.

If this sounds confusing, remember that WPF is a *retained* drawing system. That means `OnRender()` might better be called `AccumulateDrawingObjects()`. It's actually accumulating a tree of live drawing objects, some of which (like DrawingGroup, RenderTargetBitmap, and WriteableBitmap) can be updated later.

This is what it looks like:

```
DrawingGroup backingStore = new DrawingGroup();

protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) {      
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);            

    Render(); // put content into our backingStore
    drawingContext.DrawDrawing(backingStore);
}

// I can call this anytime, and it'll update my visual drawing
// without ever triggering layout or OnRender()
private void Render() {            
    var drawingContext = backingStore.Open();
    Render(drawingContext);
    drawingContext.Close();            
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into similar issue and found an even more elegant solution. Define a DependencyProperty like so:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PropertyName", typeof(PropertyType), typeof(PropertyElementType), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DefaultPropertyValue, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

The key here is this:

```
FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender
```

So now the property can be set in XAML and updates visual automatically on changing.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms598919(v=vs.100).aspx

You have to call InvalidateVisual for the Control that shall be updated. But as you can read, a call to InvalidateVisual causes a complete layout cycle, so be sure for performance reasons that your canvas or whatever you want to draw on contains no or only a few child elements.