# OnRender not called after InvalidateVisual()

Tags: wpf, prism, onrender

A custom WPF Control overrides OnRender. The method generates and displays a Path from custom data. The data provider is bound using a Dependency Property. The Dependency Property registers for an event when data changed. This event in turn calls InvalidateVisual().

However, after the InvalidateVisual() the OnRender is not always called.

We use the Prism Framework and the Region functionallity. The Control in question is embedded in such a Region, which is activated and deactivated. However, the Control's property "IsVisible" is true whenever the region is active. But still, when calling InvalidateVisual() the OnRender method is not called...

What could prevent the OnRender method from being called?

Comment: Did you consider to set [FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions.aspx) on the dependency property, instead of manually invalidating the control?

Comment: Yes I considered that and using it on several properties. However, the property in question binds to a legency (out of my control) object. On this dependency properties PropertyChangedCallback, I register to the event. And in this event handler, I call InvalidateVisual()...

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem, too.

### Context

I've got a load of controls based on the DynamicDataDisplay graph components inside a VirtualizingStackPanel (inside a ListBox).

When there are more controls that are visible at once, but not enough for the VirtualizingStackPanel to start re-using them when you scroll then I see this issue with the D3 AxisControl class. For some reason it does a lot of work in it's OnRender method, which it tries to trigger by calling InvalidateVisual when something changes.

In the problem case the problem controls call InvalidateVisual but they never get a call to MeasureOverride, ArrangeOverride *or* OnRender. Interestingly, most of the controls still work, in one particular problem case I get the last 3 out of a set of 11 failing to work properly. Notably those 3 (and only those 3) receive a call to MeasureOverride immediately before the data binding update that triggers the call to InvalidateVisual.

### My Fix

In the end I managed to fix it by adding a call to InvalidateMeasure alongside the call to InvalidateVisual.

It's a horrible solution, but it's not a performance critical part of our application, so I seem to be getting away with it.

Answer (score 1):

If the size of your control is staying the same, you should not be using `InvalidateMeasure()` or `InvalidateVisual()` because they trigger an expensive re-layout.

WPF is a *retained* drawing system. `OnRender()` might be better called `AccumulateDrawingObjects()`, because it doesn't actually draw. It accumulates a set of drawing objects which WPF uses to draw your UI whenever it wants. The magic thing is, if you put a `DrawingGroup` into the `DrawingContext` during `OnRender()`, you can actually efficiently update it *after* `OnRender`, anytime you like.

See my answer here for more details..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44426783/519568

Answer (score -1):

I just had this problem, too.

I had a scrollbar for a control which only figured out during `OnRender()` how much space is really needed to display all content, which could be bigger than the available display space and therefor needed a scrollbar. It could happen that `OnRender()` called some methods which ultimately changed the value of the scrollbar which was supposed to start `OnRender()` with `InvalidateVisual()`.

However, `OnRender()` did not get called again after `InvalidateVisual()`. I guess the reason is that `InvalidateVisual()` sets some flags which tells WPF that the control needs to get drawn again, but once `OnRender()` finishes, that flag gets reset. Here some pseudo code how I expect it to happen:

```
//someCode:
  control.InvalidateVisual()
    //code of InvalidateVisual()
    control.RedrawFlag = true;

//WPF some time later:
  if (control.RedrawFlag){
    control.OnRender()
      //OnRender code
      //do some stuff
      //decide control needs to be redrawn
      //however, RedrawFlag  is alreday true!
      //next line is not changing anything
      control.RedrawFlag = true; 

    //WPF finished executing control.OnRender
    control.RedrawFlag = false;
  }
```

I didn't further investigate if WPF really works this way, but it would explain why `OnRender()` does not get called a second time.

Instead of wasting even more time, I changed how to calculate the total width of the control content can be and put this code outside of `OnRender()`.